# Dynamically allocate C struct and access members based on the struct memory

Tags: c, struct, malloc

In a C (ANSI) program I have a struct defined as:

```
typedef struct Contacts {
    char * name;
    char * email;
    char * phone;
    struct Contacts *next;
} aContact;
aContact *paContact;
```

Based on the length of the data that I am about to store, is it possible to allocated memory as (Option 1):

```
paContact = (struct Contacts *) malloc(sizeof (struct Contacts) +strlen(theName) + strlen(theEmail) + strlen(thePhone) + 3);
```

and then do something like (pseudocode):

```
paContact->name = paContact;
paContact->email = paContact + strlen(name) + 1;
paContact->phone = paContact->email + strlen(email) + 1;
```

Or do I have to allocate memory for each member individually as  (Option 2):

```
paContact->name = (char*) malloc(sizeof (char)*strlen(name) + 1);
paContact->email = (char*) malloc(sizeof (char)*strlen(email) + 1);
paContact->phone = (char*) malloc(sizeof (char)*strlen(phone) + 1);
```

If Option 1 is not possible, what would be the proper way to keep track of all the allocated pieces of memory so that I could eventually free them?

Thank you!

Comment: Option 1 is Ok. You can avoid memory fragmentation.   Option 2. is also Ok.  But you need to free each field of aContact before you free the structure.

Comment: Option 1 requires you point the pointers *after* the struct memory, otherwise you’ll overwrite the pointers themselves with data. Otherwise it can work.

Comment: @stensal It seems you answered in a comment. Please consider making an answer, in order to get the question out of the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: You will want to visit [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either technique.  If you might need to edit the fields after creating the structure, then separate allocations are probably more appropriate.  If there'll be no need to edit the fields, then a single allocation only requires a single deallocation — and also reduces the fragmentation of memory.  There is some overhead for each allocation.

If you use the single allocation, you'll need to fix the assignments.  This code doesn't check the memory allocations, but should.

```
size_t len_name = strlen(theName);
size_t len_email = strlen(theEmail);
size_t len_phone = strlen(thePhone);
aContact *paContact = malloc(sizeof(*paContact) + len_name + len_email + len_phone + 3);

char *data = (char *)paContact + sizeof(*paContact);
paContact->name = data;
strcpy(paContact->name, theName);
data += len_name + 1;
paContact->email = data;
strcpy(paContact->email, theEmail);
data += len_email + 1;
paContact->phone = data;
strcpy(paContact->phone, thePhone);
paContact->next = NULL;
```

It might, however, be easier to use POSIX [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html):

```
aContact *paContact = malloc(sizeof(*paContact));
paContact->name  = strdup(theName);
paContact->email = strdup(theEmail);
paContact->phone = strdup(thePhone);
paContact->next  = NULL;
```

If necessary, you can write a surrogate for `strdup()` very easily:

```
char *str_dup_surrogate(const char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str) + 1;
    char *result = malloc(len);
    if (result != NULL)
        memmove(result, str, len);
    return result;
}
```

Note that the name `str_dup_surrogate()` avoids the future directions for the C library specified in C11 [§7.31.13 String handling `<string.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.31.13).  I'd be tempted to shorten it to `str_dup()`, which likewise is a user-definable name.

Comment: Quibble, choice of `len` for `size` may be visually confusing at first in the surrogate `:)`

Comment: It's the  length of the block of memory that needs to be allocated — it works for me. :D  It's a question of taste; mine is poisoned by many years using `len ` for any length.

Comment: Ah hah! Now I see it.